# Magento 2 - Add new field to Megaplaza_Blog Post

Tags: magento2, database, adminform, blog

I have a problem adding a new field to Megaplaza_Blog Post.

I've modified UpgradeSchema to modify DB and add a new column.
Column was created successfully.

I've added some code to

> /app/code/Mageplaza/Blog/Block/Adminhtml/Post/Edit/Tab/Post.php

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'name2',
        'text',
        [
            'name2'  => 'name2',
            'label' => __('Short Title (athletes)'),
            'title' => __('Short Title (athletes)'),
            'note' => __('Short Title (athletes)'),
        ]
    );
```

In admin>Megaplaza>Post>Edit I can see the value of this column from database in Input field.
When I try to save, $fieldset is being rested and every thing from modified code is gone, and i'm getting (from

> app/code/Mageplaza/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php

`

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('post');
print_r($data);die();
```

> Array ( [short_description] =>short dec2[post_content]
>   =>123[store_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [image] => Array ( [value] => /1/4/14851838971112.png ) [enabled] => 1 [in_rss] => 1 [allow_comment]
>   => 1 [url_key] => qrq2341-123 [meta_title] => [meta_description] => [meta_keywords] => [meta_robots] => INDEX,FOLLOW [categories_ids] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 8 ) )

Correct output should be like this

```
Array ( [post_id] => 11 [author_id] => 1 [name] => abcdef123 [name2] => 123123 [short_description] =>short dec2[post_content] =>123 [store_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [image] => Array ( [value] => /1/4/14851838971112.png ) [enabled] => 1 [in_rss] => 1 [allow_comment] => 1 [url_key] => qrq2341-123 [meta_title] => [meta_description] => [meta_keywords] => [meta_robots] => INDEX,FOLLOW [categories_ids] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 8 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in `'name2'  => 'name2',` should be `'name'  => 'name2',`.

Now i can't display Name2 on front end side by `$_post->getName2()`.

but when i do `print_r($_post->debug());` i'm getting [name2],

```
Array([post_id] => 2 [name] => test2 wef 243 fef [name2] => 1234nazwa211245 [short_description] => wefwef[post_content] => aefwef 
[store_ids] => 1
[enabled] => 1
[url_key] => test2-12
[in_rss] => 1
[allow_comment] => 1
[meta_robots] => INDEX,FOLLOW
[created_at] => 2017-05-19 10:20:00
[updated_at] => 2017-05-29 11:27:10
[author_id] => 1
[modifier_id] => 1
[topic_ids] => Array()
```

)